# How to flatten a dataframe column into columns and filter it?

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I converted a JSON file into a Pandas dataframe.

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFjOv.jpg)

I want to flatten the 'pos' column into the following columns and filter it:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQZ7i.jpg)

What should I do?

Comment: Assuming you have the original data in a variable called `orig`: `pd.DataFrame({'word': [x[4]{'word'} for x in orig['pos']], 'tag': [x[3] for x in orig['pos']]})`

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks. the right syntax is: `pd.DataFrame({'word': [x[4]['word'] for x in orgi['pos']], 'tag': [x[3] for x in orgi['pos']]})`

Comment: @nima, you're right. (Given copy-and-pasteable code, I would more likely have actually tested my solution before posting, and posted as an answer rather than a comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['word']=df['pos'].apply(lambda x: x[4]['word'])
df['tag']=df['pos'].apply(lambda x: x[3])
```